# How to create a 4-axes chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

4 parts to the chart: Time to expiration, Implied Volatility, Stock price, Greek 'ABC' (the plotted value).

Ideally, it would have Implied Volatility (IV) on the Z-axis, stock price on the X-axis, Greek 'ABC' on the Y-axis, then a slider or something that I can use to scroll the chart through time "axis."

I'm open to other programs as well, but it would be highly cumbersome to constantly copy 6+ Greeks worth of data from one program to the next. For every single stock I research... Each day.

(Here is a non-Excel example with only 2 axes + time slider: https://optionstrat.com/build/long-call/AAPL/220422C170)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Pivot charts using the 3-D surface chart.

For the 4th dimension, play around with using just the pivot filters, or "insert slicers" and "timelines".

With a bit of VBA coding, you could even add a slider object to your chart that controls the filter values.